# "crontab" vs "crontab -" when piping into it?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Is there any difference when piping a text into crontab versus crontab - (Which I assume confirms it to use stdin)?

On my Linux machine, doing `cat "1 0 0 0 0 something" | crontab` does the same thing as `cat "1 0 0 0 0 something" | crontab -`. So should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `cat`, but you wanted an `echo` (`1 0 0 0 0 something` is not a filename).
You need the `-` telling `cron` to read the data from the pipe.
`0` is not a good value for day of month.
Together:

```
echo "1 0 * * * something" | crontab -
# or when you want to add a rule
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "1 0 * * * something")| crontab -
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant to use echo, and the 0s were simply there for syntax example. The question in mind was simply about using crontab with or without the "-", but I will just use - from now as good practise. That seems to be the consensus even though it works without. Thank you.